# Is the timing between the end of a switch statement and the next statement deterministic (independent of path)?

Tags: c++, c

I'm configuring various GPIO pins on a microcontroller (which initiates a process that I need to time) inside a switch statement and then resetting a timer counter immediately after the end of the switch statement on the assumption that the period between the last instruction of each switch case (presumably some kind of jump or return) and the first statement after the switch will be the same independently of which case was executed.

My question - is there anything in c/c++ specifications that would validate my assumptions or am I over reaching and should reset my timer inside each case explicitly?

Comment: Please don't double tag languages. C and C++ have very different specifications. Please [edit] your tags and only include the language you actually use.

Comment: Nothing in either language specification mentions timings, so you're at the mercy of your implementation.

Comment: This question would make sense for `asm`, but is meaningless when discussing higher-level languages. You can't be sure that your switch would even compile to some set of instructions and not be constant folded away. C/C++ compilers are free to choose any representation for your code as long as it behaves the same in the terms of the abstract machine (that has no notion of timings).

Comment: Not only is there no guarantee, but the time could be negative, if it exists in any meaningful sense at all. A C implementation could execute the statement after a `switch` **before** any statement in the `switch`.

Comment: Thank's all, I have moved the time critical code within each distinct switch case and reorganised so the time sensitive pin write and subsequent timer counter reset are accessed in sequential volatile writes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the assumption that the period between the last instruction of each switch case (presumably some kind of jump or return) and the first statement after the switch will be the same

This is implementation dependent behavior.  Best way to find out what's happening is to look at the assembly code generated and perform some timing profiling on your code.